# ajax request once sent on mouseover, response recieved, but should not be sent again when i mouseover on the html element again

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

i am sending an ajax request on a mouse over event and I am receiving the desired response.
But when i send again hover on the element whose request was sent, the request is sent again.

i do not want to send the request again, rather i want the page to use the response previously received.

Who to do it?? here is a sample code. - > this function is being called on mouse over, do not want to send request again on the same mouse over element.

```
function showImage(val)
{
    $("#DIV").html('<IMAGESOURCE="../adsd/ajax_loader.gif">');

    $.ajax({
        type        : "get",
        cache   : false,
        url     : "blabla.php?imgID="+val,
        data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("DIV").innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: It would be better you you can post the event handling code only.

Answer (score 1):

Set a variable to a value when the response is received and check for that variable before send ing the request.

```
var response = false;
function showImage(val)
{
    $("#DIV").html('');
    if (response == false) {
        $.ajax({    
            type    : "get",
            cache   : false,
            url     : "blabla.php?imgID=" + val,
            data    : $(this).serializeArray(),
            success: function(data)
            {
                document.getElementById("DIV").innerHTML = data;
                response = true;
            }            
        });
    } else {
        // What to do if the request was sent before
    }
};
```

Comment: NICE and helpful.. this solution gives me another query... 

How will i display the image received on the request sent before?? on mouse over?? thanks for you help, Ibrahim.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you want to do... But I assume that the response would be the `<img/>` element? In that case, you would not need an `else` case. Otherwise, can you tell me exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

What I think is you need to use [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) on mouseover do

```
if(!jQuery.data(dom, 'sent')){
  //take action
  jQuery.data(dom, 'sent', true);// do it on success
}
```

Comment: if(!jQuery.data(dom, 'sent')){

$.ajax({    
    type        : "get",
    cache   : false,
    url     : "blabla.php?imgID="+val,
    data        : $(this).serializeArray(),             
    success: function(data) {
    document.getElementById("DIV").innerHTML = data;

    }               
});

};
}

Is this what should i do?? i cant get it to wrk... : (

Comment: Note that this method currently does not provide cross-platform support for setting data on XML documents, as Internet Explorer does not allow data to be attached via expando properties. -- 

I am no expert but this doesnt sound good. what say???

Comment: Have you included `jQuery.data(dom, 'sent', true);` at the end of your `success function` ? I am not updated with jQuery for long. So I cant say whats teh current scenario. years ago when I did this I used jQuery.data in multiple browsers without problems. I can remember more :(